# onclick attribute with JavaScript works but not if an equivalent function is called

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

This works with the `onclick` attribute:

```
<button type="button" onclick="this.style.color='red';">Astringents</button>
```

This works in the onclick attribute but not if called from the head element:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function red() {
        this.style.color='red';
    }
    </script>
</head>

<button type="button" onclick="red();">Astringents</button>
```

**EDIT:** I want to use one function to serve several buttons. For example:

```
<button type="button" onclick="red();">Astringents</button>
<button type="button" onclick="red();">Exfoliators</button>
<button type="button" onclick="red();">Moisturizers</button>
<button type="button" onclick="red();">Masques</button/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this scenario, `this` is not referencing the `<button>` element - and therefore cannot edit a property of the element.

Check out the quirksmode article on this topic
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Based on the example at the bottom of the article, the following should work.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function red(obj) {
    obj.style.color='red';
}
</script>
</head>

<button type="button" onclick="red(this)">Astringents</button>
```